# Using Hardcoded Types in an ASP.NET MVC Application w/ Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

What is a good way to handle/organize/use Hardcoded Types with an ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework?

By Hardcoded Types I mean static types defined in the business logic that will not be manageable by the User, only the developer. i.e. ProductTypes, CustomerStatuses, etc..

**I am trying to achieve a couple of things:**

1. Works well with Entity Framework data binding
2. Will be able to populate MVC View DropDownLists easily (assuming my ViewModel will be able to have a list of the type)
3. Will have a reliable valued stored in SQL (whether it is a string or Id)
4. Will be able to use in if/case statements throughout business logic

**Using Enums:**
For example lets say I have a Product entity which has a Type field.
My first instinct is to create an Enum directly in the class called ProductType with its values. However if I use enums throughout I am worried that I won't be able to accomplish the 4 above requirements.

**Using GlobalConstants**
In the past I have also created a GlobalConstants file and just created a bunch of constant strings so I could use them throughout the BusinessLogic. Then in the database I would create a TypeList table (TypeName, TypeValue, FriendlyName, etc..) that stores all of these values. So basically the TypeList table would always have to stay in sync with the GlobalConstants or something would break.

Something is telling me Enums is perfect for these hardcoded types

Answer (score 1):

Just create a model for ProductType. Example:

ProductType: {int id, string name}

In the Product model class add:

```
public ProductType Type { get; set; }
```

So basically you can store the types in database.

Comment: I was thinking about going this path because I know it will work really well with EF, but then I will have a table for every single static type. I usually try to pack types like this in a single table since they all have the same fields. Is there a way to go code only with static types like this or would you recommend definitely using the database? Additionally how will I use the types in business logic with your recommendation. I.e. if PeoductType = Missing

Comment: After thinking this through I believe you are correct. I should probably just create a Model for every single type whether it is user managed or hardcoded. This means a db table will be created for every type and for the hardcoded ones I can just create a Seed or setup script that inserts the items into these tables. Then finally for business logic I can create string GlobalConstants. Does this all make sense?